# Broadband coverage data for Canada

Tags: data, canada, telecom

Is anyone aware of a dataset for Canada that is similar to http://www.broadbandmap.gov/?
I contacted Connecting Canadians (https://www.ic.gc.ca/eic/site/028.nsf/eng/h_00587.html) to confirm that they currently don't have any published map data besides the images on their site. They indicated that the data might be available after all of the contribution agreements have been signed by the various providers, but this process's timeline goes until 2019.

Answer (score 3):

It's 2019!
https://www.ic.gc.ca/app/sitt/bbmap/hm.html?lang=eng
Looks like you can search by address, and if you click on the area information tab, you can get which providers are available. This wasn’t available in 2017. If you download the map data, you don’t get provider information. Then, looking at the FAQ for that page, I found this: https://open.canada.ca/data/dataset/00a331db-121b-445d-b119-35dbbe3eedd9. You can download a kmz there (NBD Map - EN - https://www.ic.gc.ca/eic/site/720.nsf/vwapj/NBD_Map_EN.kmz/$file/NBD_Map_EN.kmz). If you load that into google earth, click on a hex and you’ll get the area information (which includes providers that claim to service that area).

Comment: Does this work with R?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to create one using a GIS application like QGIS. You can search the web for data source on broadband coverage data. There are several free shapefiles of the various regions of Canada which you can add the broadband data to.
Came across this link http://www.crtc.gc.ca/eng/publications/reports/policymonitoring/2013/cmr6.htm

Comment: Thanks! I should be more clear, what I'm looking for are shapefiles showing the broadband coverage by the different providers in an area, much like what's available at http://www.broadbandmap.gov.

Comment: Did you find/get any?